# Joining from list with duplicates in list in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, vector, attribute-joins, table

I have a vector layer that i would like to join with a list. The problem is that my vector layer does not hold any overlapping or duplicate objects, but my list does. The list does not have any geometrical data but it has an `"id"` field that corresponds with that of the vector layer.

When I'm using the join feature in the property menu i only get the first item in the list which has a corresponding `"id"` in the vector layer. Is there a way to get a new vector layer from the join that includes every item from the list with the corresponding information and polygon from the vector layer?

What I'm looking for is the following:

[image]

The list contains no geographical information, but the result does.

Hope this is clear enough, please send me a comment otherwise.

Comment: Please, do not forget about ["What should I do when someone answers my question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

An approach by a ["Virtual Layer"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-virtual-layers) through `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer`.

Query is:

```sql
SELECT
    The_vector.ID AS ID, 
    The_list.info AS info_list, 
    The_vector.info AS info_vector
FROM
    The_vector
CROSS JOIN
    The_list
    ON The_vector.ID = The_list.ID
```

[image]